# Accessibility service is consuming a lot of battery

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I am using these permissions and retrieving content from around 10 different apps. Is there a better way of doing it so that the battery consumption is far less?

```
<accessibility-service
android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeViewClicked|typeViewFocused|typeWindowStateChanged"
android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
android:notificationTimeout="100"
android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Reading events in Accessibility Service:

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    final int eventType = event.getEventType();
    String eventText = null;
    switch(eventType) {
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED:
            eventText = "Focused: ";
            break;
        case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED:
            eventText = "Focused: ";
            break;
    }

    eventText = eventText + event.getContentDescription();

    // Do something nifty with this text, like speak the composed string
    // back to the user.
    speakToUser(eventText);
    ...
}
```

Comment: how did you tested before stating about the battery life?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest re-thinking your research into battery consumption.  Don't say:

> How much total battery is my service consuming?

Rather think:

> How much battery per minute is my service consuming?

Remember, that your service stays alive on top of your applications.  It is running constantly.  So it is expected that your accessibility service will consume more battery than other applications.

This being said, the information you provided is not helpful.  None of these are the culprit.  Basic configurations are going to have a severely minimal impact on battery consumption, and could only be changed if the nature of your applications changed (you wanted it to do something else).  No, there is no golden nugget configuration mechanism to save battery.  This is the wrong question to ask.  The types of questions you want to ask are:

How much data does my app use, and can I wait until it's connected to Wi-Fi?  Do I do a lot of long calculations, that could maybe be saved up and done all at once?  Does my service cause the screen to be on longer than necessary?

Outside of this, it is just in the nature of accessibility services to consume more battery than other types of applications, and there's nothing you can do about it.